# How to disable/enable the built-in controls in excel VSTO c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I am working in excel VSTO add-in.

In excel, having built-in tabs, groups, and controls in the ribbon. I need to disable the built-in controls in the excel.

For example, under View tab and under window group have Split control. I need to disable that Split control.

[image]

In above image, View is a built-in tab and Split control is a built-in control. I need to disable this split control.

I tried by using the idmso property. I'm not sure what the value of idmso property for Split control is.

How to disable/enable the built-in controls in excel c#?

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to disable/enable built-in ribbon controls. Instead, you may consider repurposing ribbon controls, see [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Also you may re-build the ribbon UI from scratch. In that case you will be responsible to disable/enabled controls.